# extract postgresql empty table with dplyr

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

When I pull an **empty** table from PostgreSQL I can't get column names.

```
my_db <- dplyr::src_postgres(dbname="x",host="localhost",port=5432,user="x",password="x")
my_tbl <- tbl(my_db,"test_table")
```

Here I get a tibble 0 x 0

```
my_tbl
# A tibble: 0 x 0
```

Whereas I can get colnames when test_table **isn't empty**

```
colnames(my_tbl)
[1] "var1"
```

Is there a way to get colnames even when test_table has 0 rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change to `DBI::dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), ...)`, as mentioned in the [news to dplyr 0.7](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md#databases).

```
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)
library(dbplyr)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), user = "XXX", password = "XXX",
                      port = "XXX", dbname = "XXX", host = "XXX")

con2 <- dplyr::src_postgres(user = "XXX", password = "XXX",
                            port = "XXX", dbname = "XXX", host = "XXX")


empty_tibble <- tribble(~x, ~y)

dbWriteTable(con, "test", empty_tibble, overwrite = T)

# works
tbl(con, "test")
# Source:   table<test> [?? x 2]
# Database: PqConnection
# ... with 2 variables: x <lgl>, y <lgl>


# doesn't work
tbl(con2, "test")
# Source:   table<test> [?? x 2]
# Database: postgres 9.5.7 [XXX]
```